# Preserve map view camera pitch (3d angle) on setVisibleMapRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to focus my map view on a particular region, but in such a way that it doesn't break the current camera (viewing angle). When I call `setVisibleMapRect`, the camera always resets and the view becomes completely top-down.

Is there any way to either preserve the map's camera angle, or restore it after calling `setVisibleMapRect`? I can't seem to get this to work to matter what I try. To be clear, I obviously don't want the *exact* same camera, because then calling `setVisibleMapRect` would be pointless, but I want to keep the "relative angle" of the camera while still zooming in or out based on the given visible map rect.

I've even gone so far as to attempt to compute the altitude based on the angle using some trigonometry but I can't seem to get it to work properly by setting the camera immediately after calling `setVisibleRect`. I'm guessing they're not meant to be used together.

Is trying to use `setVisibleRect` with a custom camera a bad idea? Should I just try to figure out the appropriate values to set the camera to? This is tricky because the camera properties are not intuitive and there don't seem to be any handy helper methods to focus on a particular region or rect on the map while using a nonzero camera angle. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MKMapCamera` to control the pitch and altitude. You can read the settings of the camera before changing the rect and then set them again once the new rect has been set.  Here is how you set up a camera:

```
        //create camera object
        MKMapCamera *newCamera=[[MKMapCamera alloc] init];

        //set a new camera angle
        [newCamera setCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lon)];
        [newCamera setPitch:60.0];
        [newCamera setAltitude:100.0];
        [mapView setCamera:newCamera animated:YES];
```

Comment: Strangely when I do this, the camera doesn't move at all. It's as though it cancels the `setVisibleMapRect` call.

Comment: Two things to note when using a camera. 1) pitch and altitude determine the span of the map thus modifying the visibleRect. 2) Satellite maps do not support pitch, only standard 2d maps do.

Comment: any idea on how to set 3D view in Hybrid mode/satellite mode?

Comment: The camera's pitch and altitude in conjunction with setting [mapview showsBuildings:YES] are used to set the 3D angle.  However, 3D is only available in standard mode (not satellite or hybrid) only Apple's Map can show 3D satellite for current iOS. Also, for testing, 3D does not work in the simulator so you need to test on a device.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this issue is, set the pitch right after setVisibleRect.
i.e.,

```
mapView.setVisibleMapRect(yourRect, edgePadding: yourPadding, animated: true)
mapView.camera.pitch = 45
```